# Find this nice limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} 2x-(2\lfloor x \rfloor +1)\log x$$

Where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ represents floor function.

Comment: What have you tried? Based on your comment on a provided answer, it seems you know what the value is supposed to be. Are you simply testing if we can find the value or are unable to get this value yourself? If so, at which step are you stuck?

Answer (score 6):

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor/x\to1$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\log(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}[2x-(2\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\log x]=\lim_{x\to\infty}[x(2-(2\lfloor x\rfloor/x+1/x)\log x)]=-\infty.
$$

Comment: @AmanRajput It is correct. and makes sense too!

Comment: Yaa correct .. Minus infinity.. Answer. I did a small mistake.